# Altering a Lease Calculation to take into account an upfront payment

Tags: finance

I am trying to find the interest rate of a lease if we know the monthly payment amount but have an advance payment.
I have found a site with part of the calculation we need (Scenario 2 on the link below)

www.efunda.com/formulae/finance/lease_calculator.cfm

This calculation when done with Netwon-Raphson produces the correct result, but doesn't take into account the upfront payment, this seems like a simple calculation but I can't seem to find a way to implement it in the provided calculation.

The output that I am trying to match can be found [here](http://tcalc.timevalue.com/all-financial-calculators/lease-calculators/lease-rate-calculator.aspx?LEASEAMOUNT=%2420%2C000.00&PAYMENTAMOUNT=300&RESIDUAL=%2410%2C000.00&TERM=3&TERM_UNITS=Years&ADVANCEDPAYMENTS=1&COMPUTE=COMPUTE&CALCULATORID=LC06&HIDEFORMTAG=TRUE&TEMPLATE_ID=www.timevaluecalculators.com_1&PostBack=true#results).

This calculator should provide you with the example values from Scenario 2. With an Advance Payment of 1 this then pushes up the Interest Rate to 1.792% rather than 1.756%. Putting the advance payment down to 0 will produce the same Interest Rate.

I need to figure out how to adjust the calculation from Scenario 2 to take into account the Advance Payment so it produces the correct result.

To test the Newton-Raphson logic I have been using [this](http://www.astro.auth.gr/~simos/cgi-bin/NR/NewtonRaphson.pl).

When the calculation from Scenario 2 is fed into this it seems to produce the correct result so it would be a fast way to test the Newton-Raphson for anyone that wants to attempt this.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you reduce the loan amount by the advance payment?

Comment: This then adjusts the interest rate incorrectly, If we were to say the loan amount way 19,700 and there were 35 monthly payments (to account for 1 upfront payment) this would then produce an Interest Rate of 1.825%

Answer (score 1):

Close analysis of the payment details reveals one difference - the TCALC calculator demands repayment of the residual, and charges 1 additional term of interest.

**TCALC** (20,000 in 36 months with advanced payment)

> Lease Payment 34  :   \$300.00 :  \$15.76 :   \$284.24 :  \$10,269.75
>
> Lease Payment 35  :   \$300.00 :  \$15.33 : \$284.67 :    \$9,985.08
>
> Lease Residual 1  :   \$10,000.00 : \$14.91 : \$9,985.09 :    (\$0.01)

**eFunda** (19,700 in 35 months)

> 33    \$300.00 :  \$283.50 :  \$16.50 :   \$10,568.29
>
> 34    \$300.00 :  \$283.93 :  \$16.07 :   \$10,284.36
>
> 35    \$300.00 :  \$284.36 :  \$15.64 :   \$10,000.00

You can get the same result from eFunda by using a Loan Amount of $\$19,700$, a Residual of $\$9,985$ and $35$ terms, which gives an Interest Rate of $1.79148\%$.

We therefore require that if the interest rate is $i\%$, then the final value when multiplied by $1+\dfrac{i}{1200}$ gives the residual value, which strikes me as hit and miss, although there might be a way to work it into the formula.